# Abstract over arity using shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

Using shapeless we can abstract over arity using the recipe as described in their documentation.

```
import shapeless.ops.function.FnToProduct
import shapeless.{Generic, HList}
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.function._

def applyProduct[P <: Product, F, L <: HList, R](p: P)(f: F)(implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, L], fp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => R]) =
  f.toProduct(gen.to(p))

val add = (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y

applyProduct(1, 2)(add)
```

However, I'm not being able to wrap this facility, eg:

```
def applyProduct[P <: Product, F, L <: HList, R](p: P)(f: F)(implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, L], fp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => R]) =
  f.toProduct(gen.to(p))

val add = (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y

def wrapper[F](f: F) {
  applyProduct(1, 2)(f)
}

wrapper(add)
```

The compiler argues it cannot `find implicit value for parameter fp: shapeless.ops.function.FnToProduct.Aux[(A, A) => A,L => R]`

Meaning that it is not being able to turn the K-ary function into a function of K-sized HList of the same argument types.

How can I make it work?

**edit:**

Ok, so now imagine that I know the function at a certain time but I would just know the arguments at a later time, so I want to defer the evaluation

```
case class Node[P <: Product, F, L <: HList, R](f: F)(implicit gen:Generic.Aux[P, L], fp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => R]) {
  def evaluate(p: P) = {
    f.toProduct(gen.to(p))
  }
}
```

The compiler doesn't let me call:

```
val add = (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y

val n = Node(add)

//later

n.evaluate(1,2,3)
```

Can't I use partial application to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as that:

```
def wrapper[R](f: (Int, Int) => R) = {
  applyProduct(1, 2)(f)
}
```

You already defined `P` type (as `(Int, Int)`) by passing `(1,2)` inside your wrapper, so it doesn't make any sense to abstract over `F` - the only thing you can abstract over is `R` (result type)

Explanation:

`applyProduct` inside `wrapper` doesn't know anything about `F`. So, in order to implicitly find `FnToProduct.Aux[F, ...]` scala compiler needs to know some more information about what `F` is, cause the "shape" that has `FnToProduct.Aux` implicit defined over it is `(A, A) => A` (in your case it's `(Int, Int) => Int`), not just `F`, which compiler honestly tells you from the error message.

---

Response to the edit:

```
@ applyProduct(_: Int, _: Int)(add) 
res17: (Int, Int) => Int = 

@ res17(1,2) 
res18: Int = 3
```

In order to avoid type ascriptions, you could use something like your `Node` case class (using case class for just avoiding `new` isn't considered a good style), but without introducing a class (just return lambda from function). However, as in `Node` case Scala wouldn't be able to do proper type inference without passing all type arguments.

Unfortunately, you can't conveniently use even currying here (by making `f: F` a first argument) as "implicits" wouldn't resolve without passing all type arguments. Maybe there is a way to hack it, but partial application seems the most simple and easy to understand.

P.S. You could notice however that for this case such partial application is equivalent to:

```
@ val ff = add _; val f = ff() 
ff: () => (Int, Int) => Int = 
f: (Int, Int) => Int = ammonite.$sess.cmd9$$$Lambda$1978/545666041@6e7e60bb

@ f(1,2) 
res34: Int = 3
```

It would make more sense to have a function that takes two (or List of) arguments (reducer), but gets converted to function of arbitrary arity, like `def abstract[...](f: (A, A) => A)(p: P): A`. That would be more true abstraction over arity.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Now that you say it it seems obvious why it didn't compile. However, I believe I would have stayed around this for a really long time. But isn't it possible to abstract over `F`? I mean, here it doesn't make sense since I'm fixing the `(1,2)`. But generally I mean

Comment: @raulferreira "isn't it possible to abstract over F?" Sure, that's what you were doing in the first place  and it worked :). Talking seriously, if you mean abstracting over `F` inside a wrapper, the requirements are same as for `applyProduct`: you have to ask caller for "implicits" again, aka `wrapper[F, ...](f: F)(implicit gen, fp)` - depending on the case you might need less type and implicit parameters (like you might not need to repropagate`gen` if you know arity in advance).

Comment: Yes, I see, I would need to go back to the original declaration, got it thanks! Still, my use case is a bit different. I've made an edit, maybe you can understand my purpose more clearly. I'm really a beginner in scala

Comment: @raulferreira added partial application example

Comment: thanks again for your answer @dk14. Coming from python things just seem a lot harder in scala. Is like you need to formalize every reasoning you make